# Data annotations not create one-to-many object references

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm missing something when using the data annotations.

This is my first class

```
[Table("PriceFeed")]
public class PriceFeed : History
{
    public PriceFeed()
    {
        this.Votes = new List<PriceVote>();
        this.History = new List<PriceFeed__History>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Store")]
    public long Store_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public long Item_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Store Store { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PriceFeed__History> History { get; set; }

}
```

And this is my second class

```
[Table("PriceFeed__History")]
public class PriceFeed__History : History
{

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriceFeed")]
    public long PriceFeed_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual PriceFeed PriceFeed { get; set; }

}
```

When I run the add-migration, it creates the database correctly but when I try to access PriceFeed.History it gives me an error

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Verdinhas.Web.Contexts.PriceFeed' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'PriceFeed__History'."
```

I always worked with API Fluent and typed by myself the code like

```
.Entity<Student>()
                .HasRequired<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
                .WithMany(s => s.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.StdId);
```

But now I'm using the data annotations and when I generate the migration, it does not create the "withmany" like the above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The exception message is coming from some query (with `Include`) that you haven't shown.

Comment: I'm using the repository pattern and calling the pricerepository including the history table, like this PriceRepository.Get(x => x.Id == priceId, null, "Store,Item,PriceFeed__History");

Comment: Well, there you go - it should be the property name, e.g. "Store,Item,History"

Comment: Nice @IvanStoev thanks! :) Can you write an answer so I can mark it correctly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with Data Annotations which seems to be correct in your model.

As mentioned in the comments, the exception is caused by a code that tries to use `Include` method with `string` "'PriceFeed__History" - you seem to think that you should specify the related entity **types**, but in fact you need to specify the navigation **property names**, which in your case is "History".